# Remove javascript when on ipad

Tags: javascript, html, css, ipad, parallax.js

I have a parallax scrolling site that i do not want to work on iPad. So i want to remove the link to my parallax.js file when on iPad.

How would I disable parallax scrolling on detection of device ?

Any direction would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please share the parallax.js code. It would be quite helpful for us to isolate the issue. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Use something like:

```
var is_ipad = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') > -1
```

Then dont attach the events that activate the parallax

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thread that should allow you to catch other mobile devices: [What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/best-way-to-detect-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Here's a snippet, but don't ignore the many other useful responses:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```